# display some texts under "Search box" in magento

Tags: search

Please visit this link :

http://www.snapdeal.com/

how to display some words below search box as like above website.

than customers can easily find top searched terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get top searched terms in magento use the following code

```
<?php $topsearchterms=Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->getCollection()
     ->setPopularQueryFilter()
     ->setPageSize($limit); ?>

<?php foreach($topsearchterms as $topsearchterm){ ?>
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'catalogsearch/result/?q='.$topsearchterm->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $topsearchterm->getName(); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Put the above code near your searchbox.if you want to know where is the searchbox code is please enable magento template hint and put their.

Comment: hi, 

thanks a lot for reply.

can you please inform me in detail about in which file, i have to place this code....

thanks in advance....

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: okay, i will try and let you know.....

Comment: change this to ->setPageSize(5);

Comment: thanks a lot,

visit now, how to bring those search terms under "search box" and how to make those terms

"clickable"..?...

Comment: you need to apply some css

Comment: i want those texts to be clickable. what i have to do..?...

Comment: see my edited answer